# Hide element after remove item and if request success , so remove it , Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 4.3.3. I'd like to know how I can hide a `<div>` if user clicks on remove link, and if request succeeds, so remove it, elseif request failed, so show element again.

This is the typescript code of remove:

```
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

...

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private globals: Globals, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

    deleteComment(url, index) {
        this.http.delete(url).subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log('success');
        },
        err => {
            console.log('Error occured.');
        });
    }
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of result?.comments; let i = index">
    <a (click)="deleteComment(comment?._links.delete.href, i)">remove {{comment?.id}}</a>

    <div class="media-body">
        <small>{{comment?.createdAt|date:'shortDate'}}</small>
        <p>{{comment?.content}}</p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the comments a "show" field (initially all set to true) then toggle that when remove link is clicked. If the element is successfully removed, splice element out of the array and force ngFor to re-render. If the remove fails, show the element

```
// html
<!-- Use [hidden] directive to hide element if show === false -->
<div *ngFor="let comment of result?.comment" [hidden]="comment.show">
    <!-- Other HTML -->
</div>

// ts
deleteComment(url, index) {
    // hide element
    this.result.comments[index].show = false; 

    this.http.delete(url).subscribe(
    res => {
        console.log('success');
        // remove element from array
        this.result.comments.splice(index, 1); 
        // needed to copy array. this allows ngFor to detect that the array has changed, causing ngFor to re-render 
        this.result.comments = this.result.comments.slice(0); 
    },
    err => {
        console.log('Error occurred.');
        // show element if api failed
        this.result.comments[index].show = true;
    });
}
```

**Updated**

Changed the use of ngIf directive to [hidden] directive so the element is hidden as opposed to un-rendered (as per Shane's comment)

Comment: To expand on the above, you can also do `[hidden]="comment.show"` directly at the div without having to wrap the existing markup inside a new element (`ng-template`). `<div [hidden]="comment.show" *ngFor="let comment of result?.comment">`

Comment: @ShanevandenBogaard good point, I believe that is the more correct approach because we want to hide the element as opposed to un-rendering it. I'll update my answer

Comment: @LLai, Hi what is "comments" in `this.result.comments[index].show = false;` ? I do not have a variable with this name

Comment: I have made some changes in your codes and it works now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

set boolean property
successfullyDeleted: Observable 
to true in success/false in error

use *ngIf="sucessfullyDeleted | async" in area you want to hide

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to **LLai** but with some changes.

```
    deleteComment(url, index) {
    this.result['comments'][index].hidden = true;
    this.http.delete(url).subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log('success');
            this.result['comments'].splice(index, 1);
        },
        err => {
            console.log('Error occured.');
            this.result['comments'][index].hidden = false;
        }
    );
}
```

Th HTML code

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of result?.comments; let i = index" [hidden]="comment.hidden">
<a (click)="deleteComment(comment?._links.delete.href, i)">remove {{comment?.id}}</a>

<div class="media-body">
    {{comment?.content}}
</div>
```